# $\mathbb{P} \left(\cup A_{i}\right)-\mathbb{P} \left(\cup B_{i}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\mathbb{P}(A_{i})-\mathbb{P}(B_{i})|$

Tags: probability, set-theory

I have this question but I'am a little stuck.

let $ A_n , B_n$ sequence of events 
if $\ \forall i\ B_{i}\subseteq A_{i}$ then $\mathbb{P}\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}} A_{i}\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}B_{i}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\mathbb{P}(A_{i})-\mathbb{P}(B_{i})|$

what have I done :
$\displaystyle \ \sum _{i=1}^{\infty } |\mathbb{P}( A_{i}) -\mathbb{P}( B_{i}) |=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\mathbb{P}( A_{i}) -\mathbb{P}( B_{i}) =\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\mathbb{P}( A_{i}) -\sum _{1\leqslant i< j}\mathbb{P}( B_{i} \cap B_{j}) +\sum _{1\leqslant i< j}\mathbb{P}( B_{i} \cap B_{j}) -\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } \ \mathbb{P}( B_{i})$

because $\displaystyle \forall i\ B_{i} \subseteq A_{i} \ \Rightarrow \ \forall i\forall j\ B_{i} \cap B_{j} \subseteq A_{i} \cap A_{j} \ \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}( B_{i} \cap B_{j}) \leqslant \mathbb{P}( \ A_{i} \cap A_{j})$

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
\geqslant \sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\mathbb{P}( A_{i}) -\sum _{1\leqslant i< j}\mathbb{P}( A_{i} \cap A_{j}) -(\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } \ \mathbb{P}( B_{i}) -\sum _{1\leqslant i< j}\mathbb{P}( B_{i} \cap B_{j}) )\\
\ \geqslant \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty } A_{i}\right) -\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty } B_{i}\right) -\sum _{1\leqslant i< j}\mathbb{P}( A_{i} \cap A_{j}) \ 
\end{array}$

but now I am stuck and cant find a way to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outcome in $\bigcup_i A_i \backslash \bigcup_i B_i$ is in some $A_i$ but not in any $B_j$ (and thus is in $A_i \backslash B_i$).  So
$$ \bigcup_i A_i \big\backslash \bigcup_i B_i \subseteq \bigcup_i (A_i \backslash B_i)$$